# How to decode data to html - Ckeditor 5

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

Hello I have a stupid question... about ckeditor 5 (in javascript).
I can't generate html as output. I have some kind of code that replaces tags with ## , # or *

Do you know how to configure the option when creating the editor?

```
<div class="form-group{% if property.required %} required{% endif %}">
    <label for="{{ property.name }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{ property.description }}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" id="{{ property.name }}" name="{{ property.name }}" placeholder="{{ property.description }}">
{{ bean[property.name] }}</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
ClassicEditor
     .create( document. querySelector( '#{{ property.name }}' ), {
         licenseKey: '',
         autosave: {
             save(editor) {
                 console.log(editor.getData());
             }
         }
     } )
     .then(editor => {
         window. editor = editor;
     })
     .catch(error => {
         console. error('Oops, something went wrong!');
         console.error( 'Please, report the following error on https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues with the build id and the error stack trace:' );
         console.warn('Build id: micsp245aaqe-k0zg3p5a2flq');
         console. error( error );
     } );
```

As you can see my editor.getData() returns me

```
# Hello 
World
```

instead of

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
<p>world<p>
```

Comment: try removing the code `that replaces tags with ## , # or *` because to my understanding `.getData()` will return text with tags